# Is there an alternative to touch-automation than AutoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, automation

I want to automate repetitive actions for a game on my (jailbroken) iPhone 4. I hesitate to mention the name of the game in case you would be abetting me in violation of its Terms of Service (ToS) by automation, but its player-base recommends replaying the tutorial to reroll an early game RNG element. The tutorial is easy but time-consuming, making it a prime target for automation. I stumbled across [AutoTouch](http://autotouch.me/) in the Cydia store, but it requires purchasing a license to run scripts for longer than a minute or some-length and I am skeptical of its performance. So, is there an (preferably cheaper) alternative to touch-automation than AutoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any other option (cheaper) that I've heard of.  Most of the unique tweaks in the jailbreak world are always priced high.

You should probably tweet to the developer [@KentKrantz](https://twitter.com/KentKrantz)
and ask him about AutoTouch performance on iPhone 4 running iOS7 or maybe ask him for a trial license after which if you're interested you could buy the full license for **$5** which doesn't seem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing (31/08/2021), a lot has changed.

## AutoTouch

### Licensing / Cost

AutoTouch used to have a one-time license fee, but now has a subscription model which can be viewed on https://license.autotouch.net/ and is as follows:

[image]

Note that the key difference between iOS Basic and Pro is the availability of JSBridge in the latter, which is [described](https://docs.autotouch.net/js/jsbridge.html) as follows:

> What is JSBridge?
> JSBridge is a mechanism implemented the ability to call classes, methods, variables of Objective-C from JavaScript.

### My experience

I have had quite a good experience with AutoTouch (the last time I used it was with iOS 10).

To put it in perspective, I know of very few tweaks that cost around the USD 10.00 mark (IntelliscreenX, PwnTunes, and PKGBackup come to mind). However, nowadays there are devs who only make their tweaks available on a subscription model (via Patreon), so the subscription model is no longer unique in the world of Jailbreak Tweaks.

In the yester-years (iOS 10), AutoTouch only supported Lua as the scripting language, however since v7.0.0. it also supports Javascript (See [this](https://docs.autotouch.net/js/)), which should make it immediately useful for more devs, [if I dare say so](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#most-popular-technologies-language).

Overall, Autotouch has been around for many years ( [since iOS8 atleast](https://docs.autotouch.net/release-notes/#v3-5-3)), and has seen continuous support and improvements. During this time, other contenders have come and gone only to end up abandoned.

tl;dr: Is it worth the money?
Based on my experience, YES ... BUT read on.

## Competition

### ZXTouch:

Source Code: https://github.com/xuan32546/IOS13-SimulateTouch
Cydia/Zebra etc Repository: https://zxtouch.net/

Release post: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/mmub05/free_release_you_asked_for_it_and_now_it_comes/

This is a great comparison of AutoTouch vs ZXTouch :

[image]

## Final Words

For serious automation, personally, I would pay for an AutoTouch license. ZXTouch looks very promising indeed but remains to be seen if it is supported after iOS 14 or if it will join the ranks of abandonware. For instance, there are already signs of trouble for ZXTouch, see https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/p1edwp/discussion_what_happened_to_zxtouch/